# Debian 8 openSIPS starts before MySQL on boot end exits with MySQL error

Tags: debian, services

I installed and configured openSIPS 2.3 with MySQL on a Debian 8.10 but on boot openSIPS wont start because it starts before MySQL and can't connect to the database. After the system booted up can start opensips without error.

I found what it looked like a solution on an openSIPS mailing list, but I still get the same error.

What I did so far is editing `/etc/init.d/opensisp` and cahanged init info to this

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          opensips
# Required-Start:    $syslog $network $local_fs $time
# Required-Stop:     $syslog $network $local_fs
# Should-Start:      mysql #added this
# Should-Stop:       mysql #and this
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start the OpenSIPS SIP server
# Description:       Start the OpenSIPS SIP server
### END INIT INFO
```

than I run `insserv -v opensips` and rebooted, but its the same opensisp fails with couldn't connect to db error

```
ERROR:db_mysql:db_mysql_connect: driver error(2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
ERROR:db_mysql:db_mysql_new_connection: initial connect failed
```

according to `/ętc/rc?.d` mysql should start before opensips but its not what happens or mysql isn't fully started when opensips starts.

here is a dump of `rc` for mysql and opensips

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 febr  23 21:56 /etc/rc0.d/K02mysql -> ../init.d/mysql
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 febr  23 21:56 /etc/rc1.d/K02mysql -> ../init.d/mysql
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 febr  23 21:56 /etc/rc2.d/S03mysql -> ../init.d/mysql
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 febr  23 21:56 /etc/rc3.d/S03mysql -> ../init.d/mysql
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 febr  23 21:56 /etc/rc4.d/S03mysql -> ../init.d/mysql
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 febr  23 21:56 /etc/rc5.d/S03mysql -> ../init.d/mysql
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 febr  23 21:56 /etc/rc6.d/K02mysql -> ../init.d/mysql

############

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 febr  25 01:17 /etc/rc0.d/K01opensips -> ../init.d/opensips
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 febr  25 01:17 /etc/rc1.d/K01opensips -> ../init.d/opensips
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 febr  27 10:40 /etc/rc2.d/S04opensips -> ../init.d/opensips
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 febr  27 10:40 /etc/rc3.d/S04opensips -> ../init.d/opensips
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 febr  27 10:40 /etc/rc4.d/S04opensips -> ../init.d/opensips
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 febr  27 10:40 /etc/rc5.d/S04opensips -> ../init.d/opensips
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 febr  25 01:17 /etc/rc6.d/K01opensips -> ../init.d/opensips
```

How can I force openSIPS to wait for mysql?

Comment: Debian 8 does not use sysvinit by default; it uses systemd. Have you configured it to use sysv?

Comment: No, I have not. But if I'm not mistaken insserv should have taken care of the order when I specified `should-start` in the LSB

Comment: Ok, have edited the sysV out from your question, it is misleading. You are using systemd then. I am not so used to systemd, we will wait someone else to answer you.

Comment: Ok thanks. I probably clicked on it by accident.

Comment: Thanks @A.B but it turns out that the opensips.servise file was depending on a non existing mysqld.service by checking `systemctl status mysql` I found out that it should be mysql.service because mysql doesn't have a systemd service.